# Is there a way to make a new string variable from a reversed string variable?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, foreach

The code I have used to reverse the original string is...

`foreach (var revString in strExample.Split(' ').Reverse()) Console.WriteLine(revString);`

However I am struggling to create a new string variable following this method. Can anyone help me out. I am new to coding and don't fully understand everything yet.

Comment: What do you want your new string variable to contain? All of the space-separated words? E.g. if the original is "Foo bar" the final result would be "ooF rab"?

Comment: No, using your example I would want my final result to be "bar foo" @eric J.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String.Join() does the reverse of String.Split(), so you can do this:

```
var strExample = "Foo bar";
var reversed = string.Join(' ', strExample.Split(' ').Reverse());
```

> bar Foo

If you also wanted to reverse the letters within each word (original comment before edited):

```
var fullyReversed = 
    string.Join(' ', strExample.Split(' ')
    .Select(word => new string(word.Reverse().ToArray())));
```

> ooF rab

or more simply:

```
new string(strExample.Reverse().ToArray());
```

Comment: Brilliant , Thanks for your help Eric! :)